# Python - What happens when getting circular loop of dependancies in trying to install packages

Tags: python, numpy, pip, yfinance

Im trying to install yfinance

I get an error saying it needs FuzzyTM. When I try to install FuzzyTM it tells me I need to install numpy.

When I try to install numpy it tells me I need to install FuzzyTM.

I keep on finding these circular loops that I cannot resolve.

What do I do?

Also I get these messages :

conda-repo-cli 1.0.27 requires clyent==1.2.1, but you have clyent 1.2.2 which is incompatible.
conda-repo-cli 1.0.27 requires nbformat==5.4.0, but you have nbformat 5.7.0 which is incompatible.
conda-repo-cli 1.0.27 requires requests==2.28.1, but you have requests 2.29.0 which is incompatible.

Is this a pip install or is there another process for conda-repo-cli?

Thanks for looking

Comment: Have you tried to install them separately with --no-dependencies flag in pip install ?

Comment: not yet but thanks for the idea. I'm new to Python and using it on the mac is a pain with the different versions and locations